# How to identify the function parameters when calling a function written in assembly from C?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64

```
func cactus_entrypoint
    /* Entry reason is primary EC cold boot */
    mov x19, #1
secondary_cold_entry:
    /* Entry reason is secondary EC cold boot */
    mrs x0, mpidr_el1
    bl  platform_get_core_pos

    /* Setup the stack pointer. */
    adr x1, stacks_end
    mov x2, #CACTUS_STACKS_SIZE
    mul x2, x0, x2
    sub sp, x1, x2
```

The above code snippet is from cactus_entrypoint.S. The `cactus_entrypoint` and `secondary_cold_entry` function is called from a C program. In the C source code, I see declaration like this:

```
extern void cactus_entrypoint(uint64_t arg);
extern void secondary_cold_entry(void);
```

Why and how do I see that `cactus_entrypoint` takes 1 parameter and `secondary_cold_entry` does not take parameters from the assembly code?

Comment: What does the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specify for arguments in your system?

Comment: This is ARM using GCC, I am not sure what to look for. Could you give more info. about how to check?

Comment: I can't find any source with `cactus_entrypoint` defined in C. Closest thing I found is [this](https://review.trustedfirmware.org/plugins/gitiles/TF-A/tf-a-tests/+/3913795ee5daae5fb2770c1ff153ba2dc5ab9a61/spm/cactus/cactus_main.c). The first arg is in `x0`, which is overwritten immediately in both functions. It makes sense for `secondary_cold_entry` **not** to take any param, not so much for `cactus_entrypoint`. But again, I couldn't find it, so it's hard to tell what's going on. It's possible a formal parameter should be passed by convention but it's ignored by the function.

Comment: C is C and asm is asm, there is no cross over.  You as the programmer need to know the C caller or callee code and know the abi and from that know the rules for passing parameters and return values for that abi.  As either side changes you need to manually change the other.  If your question is what is the abi and what registers are used you can easily determine that with a few experimental C programs.

Answer (score 0):

```
void hello ( uint64_t );

void world ( void )
{
    hello(0x12345678AABBCCDDULL);
}

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <world>:
   0:   d2999ba0    mov x0, #0xccdd                 // #52445
   4:   f2b55760    movk    x0, #0xaabb, lsl #16
   8:   f2cacf00    movk    x0, #0x5678, lsl #32
   c:   f2e24680    movk    x0, #0x1234, lsl #48
  10:   14000000    b   0 <hello>
```